# Gradle Project sync failed. Osmdroid

Tags: android, gradle, osmdroid

I have downloaded the Osmdroid project from Github, from here https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid

When I open the osmdroid-master directory in Android Studio it attempts to sync but fails with the following error: Gradle Project sync failed.

```
Cause: startup failed:
script 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gradle-fury/gradle-fury/v1.1.4/gradle/maven-support.gradle': 1453: unable to resolve class org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction 
 @ line 1453, column 13.
               new org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction({
               ^

1 error
```

In idea.log there is:

```
2020-01-31 14:10:04,272 [entQueue-0]   WARN - un.AndroidRunConfigurationBase - Can't get application ID: Android module missing 
2020-01-31 14:10:04,402 [Alarm Pool]   INFO - mponents.impl.stores.StoreUtil - saveProjectsAndApp took 34 ms
```

I am on Ubuntu 19.04.

How can I see which Android module it's referring to as missing?

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but are you trying to modify osmdroid, or just use it in your own Android app? For the first option you might find something useful in [https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/How-to-build-OsmDroid-from-source](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/How-to-build-OsmDroid-from-source). If you just want to use osmdroid, then this is not the way.

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen thanks for your reply (not dumb at all IMO). I have tried the Building with Gradle instructions and have gotten the same error, the one referencing line 1453, column 13. I'm trying to evaluate Osmdroid to use it in my own app, I hope to not have to modify it or at least as little as possible. If you think my approach is wrong how would you suggest I proceed?

Comment: You'll add osmdroid as a Gradle dependency to your Android app project according to [https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid) and then follow the other instructions in [https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki). There's no need to grab the source code and build it yourself.

Comment: OK, thanks. I will try that and report back.

Comment: what version of gradle?

Comment: @spy Gradle 4.4.1

Comment: that's probably why... for osmdroid, use ./gradlew build

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original question was based on a misunderstand on my behalf. The Osmdroid from Github cannot be compiled into an APK.

The correct approach is to create a new empty project in Android Studio, add org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:6.1.5 to the dependencies in build.grade, then following the examples given here: https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/How-to-use-the-osmdroid-library add uses-permission, layout and then the actual code to the Main Activity. I now have a working mapping app which downloads tiles as it needs them. If I have further questions I will post separately.

Thanks to everybody who contributed.

Comment: ok, but what if you want to use the OSMMapTIlePackager?

Comment: @Maske Thank you for your input. This issue is resolved and there isn't any need for further help. All the best.

Comment: i'm getting the same error. how did you solve it ? can you post it in here. thks

Comment: @MiguelSilva The solution is as described in this answer. If you are encountering problems following the steps please post a specific question and I will try to help you.